# Overriding onDismiss or onCancel doesn't work in DialogFragment

Tags: java, android

I've implemented a fullscreen `DialogFragment` exactly as it's done in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#FullscreenDialog).

```java
public void showDialog() {
    CustomDialogFragment newFragment = new CustomDialogFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, newFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

```java
public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.purchase_items, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onCancel(dialog);
        // Code added her doesn't run on back press
    }
}
```

**Note:** The `onCancel()` and `onDismiss()` functions run properly if I open the fragment using `show()`, but that's not what I want here. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Those methods aren't supposed to run when you use it as a regular `Fragment`. Those are `Dialog` callbacks, and if you're not showing a `Dialog`, those just won't run.

Comment: @MikeM. so how am I supposed to have the same behaviour using a fragment? `onDestroyView()` won't work as it runs when the dialog is dismissed as well as cancelled with a back press.

Comment: Please, Explain what you need? Exactly what you need?

Comment: @Poran I'm opening a fullscreen dialog. I'd like to run some code on back press.

Comment: It would kinda depend on your specific setup, and what you actually need to listen for. To catch the back press popping the backstack, you can make use of an [`OnBackStackChangedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener). If you need to differentiate between a back press cancel, and the stack popping because of a `dismiss()` call, you could override `dismiss()` and add some sort of flag set there; e.g., `wasDismissed = true;`. Make sense?

Comment: @MikeM. yeah I could do it like that, but is there no easy way for a question that seems so simple? If not I guess i'll have to go with this.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no simple method or switch to make that happen, no. Now that I think about it, it's probably simpler to do something like `if (getDialog() == null) { onDismiss(null); }` in the `dismiss()` override to fully cover the `OnDismissListener`, but I'm fairly certain you'd still need something like the backstack listener to handle the back press cancel.

Comment: @MikeM. actually your suggestion gave me an idea that I'm trying out right now. Basically I'll override `dismiss()` setting a flag `isDismissed = true` inside the `DialogFragment`, and also override `onDestroyView()` to run some code if `isDismissed` is `false`. It's slightly easier.

Comment: Bhavik Kalsariya's got another good suggestion for ya below that I'd meant to mention earlier. You just could make the `Dialog` full-screen, if that would fit your design. You wouldn't have to do anything special with the listeners.

Comment: @MikeM. It's not exactly what I'm looking for, I tried it a while back and was having difficulty with the style, drawing it behind the system bars, etc. Also it doesn't have fragment transition. But it is an answer and might help others facing this issue, so I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up overriding the `dismiss()` and `onDestroyView()` functions in my `DialogFragment` to have the same behaviour while still opening it as a fragment instead of a dialog and it seems to works.

```java
public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    boolean isDismissed;
    OnCancelListener onCancelListener;

    public CustomDialogFragment(@NonNull OnCancelListener onCancelListener) {
        this.onCancelListener = onCancelListener;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.purchase_items, container, false);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void dismiss() {
        super.dismiss();
        this.isDismissed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        if (!this.isDismissed) {
            this.onCancelListener.onCancel();
        }
    }

    public interface OnCancelListener {
        void onCancel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this method to show your dialog in activity :-

```
public void showDialog() {
    CustomDialogFragment newFragment = new CustomDialogFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "show_fragment");
}
```

Add this style :-

```
<style name="FullScreenfragment" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
</style>
```

Add this code in your CustomDialogFragment :-

```
@Override
public int getTheme() {
    return R.style.FullScreenfragment;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function showDialog some problem, you can try this call show your custom dialog:

```
public void showDialog() {
    CustomDialogFragment newFragment = new CustomDialogFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "show_dialog");
}
```

Text "show_dialog", you can replace text if you want

**Edit:** if you want full screen dialog, try this:

Add custom style:

```
<style name="full_screen_dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

And set in CustomDialog:

```
public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.purchase_items, container, false);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onCancel(dialog);
    }

    @Override
    public int getTheme() {
        return R.style.full_screen_dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (getDialog() != null) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
            params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(params);
        }
    }
}
```